# Unable to boot 64-bit kernel after installation

Tags: boot, installation, 64-bit, linux-kernel, debian-buster

My system supports 64-bit architecture and I am able to use debian-buster meant for amd64 architecture separately. Now, I have an os running debian-buster having kernel as "linux-image-686-pae". I want it to use the kernel "linux-image-amd64:amd64". For that, I updated the system using `apt update` then I installed the other kernel using `apt-get` install linux-image-amd64:amd64. Then on rebooting I chose the amd64 version from the grub menu. It prints the list for starting various processes, but it just halts at that and doesn't progress further. It halts at the starting processes list printing screen. I am unable to configure the problem. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You can't just replace the kernel with a different architecture!

Comment: I want to cross-grade my system. This was mentioned [here](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossGrading)

Comment: Is your BIOS/UEFI 64-bit-capable or 32-bit-only. On some PCs, for licensing reasons more than anything else, they fit 64-bit CPUs with 32-bit-only UEFI, so that you can't boot or even install a 64-bit OS, even though the CPU would run it without breaking a sweat. With minor editing in the boot files, some Linux distros can install a 64-bit OS on those 32-bit platforms, but I'm not sure Debian dev versions are among them, not out of the box anyway. Sometimes, disabling Secure Boot can help too.

Comment: Yes it is, as I mentioned I can run the amd64 architecture with the kernel separately on dual boot of Debian Buster itself.